# Stationary solutions of a nonlinear Dirac-type equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have got a (2+1)D nonlinear differential equation which reduces to a Dirac equation in the linear case:

$$\sigma_0 \partial_t\mathbf{y}(t,x,y) = \sigma_z \partial_x \mathbf{y}(t,x,y) - \sigma_y \partial_y\mathbf{y}(t,x,y) + \mathrm{i}\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{y})\mathbf{y}(t,x,y)$$
where $\mathbf{y}(t,x,y) = [y_1(t,x,y),y_2(t,x,y)]^\mathrm{T}$ and $\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{y}) = \begin{bmatrix} |y_1|^2 & 0  \\ 0 & |y_2|^2 \end{bmatrix}.$
$\sigma_\alpha$ are the Pauli matrices with $\sigma_0$ the $2\times2$ identity matrix.

I am looking for stationary solutions to this equation (presumably the precise form will have to be numerically determined). People have looked at similar equations (e.g. [1]) and found such solutions but their equation contained only the antidiagonal Pauli matrices attached to the derivatives, so each component only depends on the derivative of the other component there. This fairly easily allows one to find a suitable Ansatz separated into a radial and angular part, where then the whole problem basically reduces to finding the radial part numerically (which is then a 1D problem).

I wonder if anyone has any good pointers on how to tackle an equation like the one above (numerically or analytically as far as that gets me).

[1] https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/17/11/113011/pdf